# how can i link a image to an anchor tag using JS?(feature on which i am working using cloud firestore, a new game adding option for admin)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
        var db = firebase.firestore();
db.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true }); 
const newgame = document.querySelector('addingnewgame');

function addnewgame(doc){
  let gamebase = document.createElement('a');
  let gamelink = gamebase.href;
  
  let gamename = gamebase.innerHTML;
  let gameimage = document.createElement('img');
  gameimage =  doc.data().gameimglink;
  gamename.innerText = doc.data().gamename;
  gamebase.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);
  gamebase.setAttribute("src" , gameimage);
  gamebase.setAttribute("href" , gamelink);
  gamebase.setAttribute("innerhtml", gamename);
  gamelink.innerText = doc.data().gameurl;
  
   newgame.appendChild(gamebase);
 }

db.collection('New Game').get().then((snapshot) => {
  snapshot.docs.forEach(doc =>
    {
      addnewgame(doc);
    })
})
```

there are few errors kindly please help me out. i am  working on  a project based on cloud firebase ,help me out to resolve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to have a link around an image.

**Working example:**

```js
let gamebase = document.createElement('a');
let gameimage = document.createElement('img');

gamebase.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask';
gamebase.setAttribute('data-id', 'some_id_from_doc');
gameimage.src = 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196';
gameimage.title = 'How do I ask a good question?';

gamebase.appendChild(gameimage);
document.querySelector('#container').appendChild(gamebase);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```